# unordered list within unordered list - select particular line item

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists

I'm building a navigation with drop down menus. I'd like the line item that contains the unordered list, subnav, to have white anchor text when hovered. I have done this but my selector has resulted in a bug with one of the drop down line items. Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/W3Dzd/
If you hover over "sui generis" and run the cursor down the menu it works fine except for "mantels" - the anchor text does not change color when hovered.
I guess that what has happened is that the selector for the 3rd line item in the main nav has also selected the 3rd line item in the subnav. 
Can someone suggest a better selector or way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is possible for you to change the code which generates your menus (or to manually change them if you are hand-coding them) you will end up with a much more robust system by applying your submenu class to the parent `li` instead of the child `ul`. Your previous code was targeting specific list items via complex selectors that would break if you rearranged your menu or added/removed items from it. The new code will handle these cases without issue.

You can see a sample of how this might work in action at this updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W3Dzd/4/

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I'm not sure which selector your suggesting I replace with your code? The long, what must be overly complex selector along the lines ".navigation li:first-child + li + li:hover > a" is an attempt to select a particular list item, not all the list items int he list? Could you clarify which selector you suggest I replace? Thanks!

Comment: @DougFirr I updated my answer to improve it a little. I am not sure what you were trying to do with that selector but it seems redundant based on its actual effect.

Comment: ah, thanks. But, now I have lost the white anchor text on hover state for the head line items "sui generis" and "reclaimed wood". It was because I wanted to select these line items only that I used the first-child + li etc. Can you suggest how to go about ensuring that these titles, "sui generis" and "reclaimed wood", have white anchor text when hovered as they did before? What would be the best selector without affecting other list items?

Comment: @DougFirr Shoot, I'm wrong. The way that I updated it does break what you were doing - now I see. Hang on a second and I will fix that for you :)

Comment: @DougFirr By the way, why are you targeting the specific items in your stylesheet? You really should change your code to put a class on the parent item. The way you have it right now creates a very fragile link between the two if you ever rearrange your menu or add items to it.

Comment: thanks for your help on this. This is only my 3rd site and am still figuring out best methods. Thanks again, your fix was really helpful.